# Spliterator vs Stream.Builder

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, builder, spliterator

I read some questions how to create a finite `Stream` (
[Finite generated Stream in Java - how to create one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047907/finite-generated-stream-in-java-how-to-create-one), [How do streams stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226823/how-do-streams-stop)).

The answers suggested to implement a `Spliterator`. The `Spliterator` would implement the logic how to and which element to provide as next (`tryAdvance`). But there are two other non-default methods `trySplit` and `estimateSize()` which I would have to implement.

The JavaDoc of `Spliterator` says:

> An object for traversing and partitioning elements of a source. The source of elements covered by a `Spliterator` could be, for example, an array, a `Collection`, an IO channel, or a generator function. ... The `Spliterator` API was designed to support efficient parallel
>   traversal in addition to sequential traversal, by supporting
>   decomposition as well as single-element iteration. ...

On the other hand I could implement the logic how to advance to the next element around a `Stream.Builder` and bypass a `Spliterator`. On every advance I would call `accept` or `add` and at the end `build`. So it looks quite simple.

What does the JavaDoc say?

> A mutable builder for a `Stream`. This allows the creation of a `Stream`
>   by generating elements individually and adding them to the `Builder`
>   (without the copying overhead that comes from using an `ArrayList` as a
>   temporary buffer.)

Using `StreamSupport.stream` I can use a `Spliterator` to obtain a `Stream`. And also a `Builder` will provide a `Stream`.

When should / could I use a `Stream.Builder`?
Only if a `Spliterator` wouldn't be more efficient (for instance because the source cannot be partitioned and its size cannot be estimated)?

Comment: It boils down to push or pull.

Comment: I just want to add that while Ive written a few Spliterators on my own, its never a fun story, it might be for Holger that is an ace at this; but if you really need advance features, Spliterator is the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you can extend [`Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/util/Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator.html). Then, there is only `tryAdvance` to implement.

So the complexity of implementing a `Spliterator` is not higher.

The fundamental difference is that a `Spliterator`’s `tryAdvance` method is only invoked when a new element is needed. In contrast, the `Stream.Builder` has a *storage* which will be filled with all stream elements, before you can acquire a Stream.

So a `Spliterator` is the first choice for all kinds of lazy evaluations, as well as when you have an existing storage you want to traverse, to avoid copying the data.

The builder is the first choice when the creation of the elements is non-uniform, so you can’t express the creation of an element on demand. Think of situations where you would otherwise use `Stream.of(…)`, but it turns out to be to inflexible.

E.g. you have `Stream.of(a, b, c, d, e)`, but now it turns out, `c` and `d` are optional. So the solution is

```
Stream.Builder<MyType> builder = Stream.builder();
builder.add(a).add(b);
if(someCondition) builder.add(c).add(d);
builder.add(e).build()
   /* stream operations */
```

Other use cases are [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077388/2711488), where a `Consumer` was needed to query an existing spliterator and push the value back to a `Stream` afterwards, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240859/2711488), where a structure without random access (a class hierarchy) should be streamed in the opposite order.

Comment: I think lazy evaluation is a very distinctive and important point. The example for `Stream.Builder` where  `c` and `d` are optional is (if I got you right) similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324648/remove-duplicates-from-a-large-unsorted-array-and-maintain-the-order). I was about to use a `Stream.Builder` to provide a solution but wasn't sure if it's appropriate.

Comment: I'm dumb and I'm very new to java and I'm seeing Stream.builder() and build() functions, Please help me understanding!!!

Comment: @nitinsridar what exactly is your question?

Comment: What is buider? I'm seeing in elasticsearch, apache kafka but I'm not getting what builder actually doing ? @Holger

Comment: @nitinsridar method [`Stream.builder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#builder()), which returns an instance of [class `Stream.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html).

Answer (score 3):

> On the other hand I could implement the logic how to advance to the next element around a Stream.Builder and bypass a Spliterator. On every advance I would call `accept` or `add` and at the end `build`. So it looks quite simple.

Yes and no.  It *is* simple, but I don't think you understand the usage model:

> A stream builder has a lifecycle, which starts in a building phase, during which elements can be added, and then transitions to a built phase, after which elements may not be added. The built phase begins when the `build()` method is called, which creates an ordered `Stream` whose elements are the elements that were added to the stream builder, in the order they were added.

([Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html))

In particular no, you would not invoke a `Stream.Builder`'s `accept` or `add` method on any stream advance.  You need to provide all the objects for the stream *in* advance.  Then you `build()` to get a stream that will provide all the objects you previously added.  This is analogous to adding all the objects to a `List`, and then invoking that `List`'s `stream()` method.

If that serves your purposes and you can in fact do it efficiently then great!  But if you need to generate elements on an as-needed basis, whether with or without limit, then `Stream.Builder` cannot help you.  `Spliterator` can.

Comment: _you would not invoke a Stream.Builder's accept or add method on any stream advance_  - I think, you got me wrong. I said, I could build the logic around a `Stream.Builder.accept`, not a `Stream` advance. I meant that I could thus add every element to a `Stream.Builder` similar like a `Spliterator.tryAdvance`provides every element.

Comment: @LuCio `tryAdvance` *potentially* provides every element, but might not get invoked for every element, as the stream might not need them. But you have to invoke `Stream.Builder.accept` or `add` for every element before you can create the stream, without knowing whether all of them are needed. Calling a method for every element or implementing a method potentially providing every element, are a fundamentally different code structures. Usually, there’s a natural choice.

Comment: @Holger Yes. This is an important difference which I just read from your answer.

Comment: @LuCio, what you wrote was "On every advance I would call `accept` or `add` and at the end `build`. "  And yes, of course you can build a stream using `Stream.Builder.advance` and ultimately `Stream.Builder.build`.  The question is timing.  As I already said, if you can feed all the elements to a `Stream.Builder` up front, before you start processing the stream, then that's fine.  But you cannot invoke `accept` or `add` in concert with advancing through the stream.  If that's not what you meant to say anyway, then well and good.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thx for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The Stream.Builder is a misnomer as streams can't really be built.  Things that can be built are value objects - dto, array, collection.
So if Stream.Builder is instead thought of as a buffer, it might help understand it better, eg:

```
buffer.add(a)
buffer.add(b)
buffer.stream()
```

This shows how similar it is to an ArrayList:

```
list.add(a)
list.add(b)
list.stream()
```

On the other hand, Spliterator is the basis of a stream and allows for efficient navigation over data sets (improved version of the Iterator).

So the answer is they should not be compared.  Comparing Stream.Builder to Spliterator is the same as comparing ArrayList to Spliterator.